# Checking if String Is Not Equal to Something

Tags: c#, string, console

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace FirstProgram
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("What is your first name?");
                String Name = Console.ReadLine ();
            Console.WriteLine ("\nHi " + Name + "! Now tell me are you a boy or girl?");
                String Sex = Console.ReadLine ();

            if (!Sex.Equals ("boy") || !Sex.Equals ("girl")) {
                Console.WriteLine ("\nERROR: You were supposed to type 'boy' or 'girl'\nPress any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey ();
                System.Environment.Exit (1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine ("\nOk so your name is " + Name + " and your are a " + Sex + "... Please tell me your age :)");
                int Age = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.WriteLine ("\nYou are " + Age + " years old!");
            Console.ReadKey ();
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to know why the program exits even though I type "boy" or "girl" and how I can fix this.

Comment: well, for one thing you need to change the `||` to `&&`

Answer (score 12):

Simple logic:

```
Sex != "boy" || Sex != "girl"
```

will always be true.

You need to use

```
Sex != "boy" && Sex != "girl"
```

instead.

A few extra notes:

- C# supports operator overloading and it's commonly used, so you can use `==` and `!=` for strings just fine.
- Don't use `Environment.Exit`, just `return`. If you need to return an error code, change the signature of `Main` to `int Main()` and `return 1;`. But note that on Windows, applications may assume that an application that returned a non-success code failed in some way and report it - e.g. Total Commander will pop up a message.
- Don't use `\n`. Either use `Environment.NewLine`, or just stick to `Console.WriteLine` for endlines.
- Consider using `string.Format` for slapping together complex strings: `string.Format("Your name is {0} and your age is {1}.", Name, Age). If you're on C# 6+, string interpolation is even nicer:`$("Your name is {Name} and your age is {Age}.")`.
- A case insensitive comparison might be more useful for your case - `Sex.Equals("boy", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change your if statement from an "OR" to an "AND":

```
if (!Sex.Equals ("boy") || !Sex.Equals ("girl"))
```

An "OR" statement evaluates to true if one of the conditions is filled. So if you enter "boy", then the second statement, `!Sex.Equals("girl")` is true, therefore it executes the code within the if statement.

Instead, use an "AND" statement, which evaluates to true only if both arguments are true.

```
if (!Sex.Equals ("boy") && !Sex.Equals ("girl"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The allowed values are `boy` or `girl`:

```
Sex.Equals ("boy") || Sex.Equals ("girl")
```

Other values are not allowed:

```
!( Sex.Equals ("boy") || Sex.Equals ("girl") )
```

Then, your if must be:

```
if (   !( Sex.Equals ("boy") || Sex.Equals ("girl") ) ) 
{
   ...
   System.Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

Or this

```
if (   ! Sex.Equals ("boy") && !Sex.Equals ("girl") ) ) 
{
   ...
   System.Environment.Exit(1);
}
```